# How to turn off tooltip showing all of my data in Plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am making a shiny dashboard application. One of the Tabs in the dashboard is for my Plotly plot. I am able to get the plot to show up just fine, but whenever I leave my mouse's cursor over the plot for more than a second, a **massive tooltip** shows up, going the length of my monitor, that displays as much of my data as can fit. This is not part of Plotly's built in hover text, which is actually useful. This is like a tooltip that shows when you hover over something on the web.

[image: This is a small part of the tooltip.]

Obviously this is unacceptable. Especially because this huge tooltip takes a second or more to load, so it bogs everything down. How do I turn this off? It's annoying and not useful at all. I assume the solution is JS or HTML related but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the plotly call. I use ggplotly because I am more familiar with customizing the plot using ggplot than plotly.

```
library(plotly)     

plot <- ggplot(mydata) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = obsAcc25, ymax = obsAcc97, x = x), fill = "cadetblue3", alpha = 0.8) 
    + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = delAcc25, ymax = delAcc97, x = x), fill = "palegreen3", alpha = 0.8) 
    + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = actAcc25, ymax = actAcc97, x = x), fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = 0.8) 
    + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey58"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey75"))


    p <- ggplotly(plot)
```

As was suggested, here is dput(head(mydata, 10))

```
structure(list(actAcc25 = c(-12.8684282283388, -12.0304436152616, 
-11.3150952252788, -10.6081847586627, -10.0552821849214, -9.55261456431379, 
-9.04799817226408, -8.63169310666002, -8.21986707344882, -7.87700068972389
), obsAcc25 = c(-29.2405337619969, -28.8889501014795, -28.504360142198, 
-28.1674808122894, -27.8980268120593, -27.5944378874029, -27.2407785909855, 
-26.9557048837549, -26.8112580628704, -26.3946724698358), delAcc25 = c(-13.2454526253711, 
-12.3943001876792, -11.7223680727026, -11.0627967149018, -10.5171275099291, 
-10.0121757711887, -9.55927026173585, -9.15474795930365, -8.7615554644258, 
-8.44377029372532), actAcc97 = c(20.5859080152232, 19.5383979476408, 
18.5967498955669, 17.9042117055988, 17.1661035121933, 16.5672919339584, 
16.0108793011971, 15.4856795165235, 15.0292972125609, 14.5904142938209
), obsAcc97 = c(39.5176394183119, 38.6324722217456, 37.9015992542866, 
37.2607649650388, 36.681699119323, 36.1958973938439, 35.6469528390747, 
35.336998047658, 34.9088544137054, 34.4801441415), delAcc97 = c(21.0663356298793, 
20.103870882492, 19.2051147569388, 18.513845516169, 17.7970734480676, 
17.1961361293244, 16.650452469565, 16.1799047501671, 15.7202776795709, 
15.2788029123616), x = c(0.4486530314, 0.5103655236, 0.5760397998, 
0.6456734834, 0.7192641994, 0.7968095744, 0.8783072362, 0.9637548142, 
1.053149939, 1.146490243)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: and here is the output of sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dashboardthemes_1.0.2 plotly_4.7.1          ggplot2_2.2.1         shinydashboard_0.7.0  shiny_1.1.0          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17      pillar_1.2.3      compiler_3.5.0    later_0.7.3       plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1.1       shinyjs_1.0       tools_3.5.0      
 [9] digest_0.6.15     viridisLite_0.3.0 jsonlite_1.5      tibble_1.4.2      gtable_0.2.0      pkgconfig_2.0.1   rlang_0.2.1       crosstalk_1.0.0  
[17] yaml_2.1.19       bindrcpp_0.2.2    dplyr_0.7.5       httr_1.3.1        htmlwidgets_1.2   grid_3.5.0        tidyselect_0.2.4  glue_1.2.0       
[25] data.table_1.11.4 R6_2.2.2          tidyr_0.8.1       purrr_0.2.5       magrittr_1.5      scales_0.5.0      promises_1.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6  
[33] rsconnect_0.8.8   assertthat_0.2.0  mime_0.5          xtable_1.8-2      colorspace_1.3-2  httpuv_1.4.3      labeling_0.3      lazyeval_0.2.1   
[41] munsell_0.5.0
```

Comment: Could you include a small example??

Comment: @SeGa Edited with my ggplotly call.

Comment: Your example should be reproducible. Include (using `dput`) `mydata` in your post.

Comment: @MLavoie how do you mean? Sorry, I am unfamiliar with making this example reproducible. I can add more information about mydata if that would help?

Comment: Yes, include a tiny fraction of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: You actually have to put the content of `dput()` in your post. As it is we can't still run your code.

Comment: @MLavoie I don't know how to post that much data without exceeding the character limit of the post.

Comment: it could be `dput(head(yourdata, 10))`.

Comment: @MLavoie added, but I'm not sure I did what you suggested correctly.

Comment: Your code is working fine. What is your plotly version?

Comment: @MLavoie I have Plotly verson 4.7.1. Is it possible that this has something to do with the fact that this plotly is appearing in a tabPanel in a shiny dashboard? Maybe there are compatibility issues.

Comment: Your code also works in shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around in the HTML of my shiny app, using Right Click -> Inspect, I was able to see that the title for my tabPanel was somehow assigned to be the entirety of my data. This is why hovering over it with my cursor caused it to display such a massive tooltip. After getting rid of the tabPanel and just putting my plot in tabItem, I was able to fix the issue, removing the tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

I am not able to reproduce your problem. For me it works with `tooltip = FALSE`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

n=10
mydata <- data.frame(
  obsAcc25 = runif(n, 1, 10),
  obsAcc97 = runif(n, 1, 10),
  delAcc25 = runif(n, 1, 10),
  delAcc97 = runif(n, 1, 10),
  actAcc25 = runif(n, 1, 10),
  actAcc97 = runif(n, 1, 10),
  x = runif(n, 1, 10)
)

plot <- ggplot(mydata) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = obsAcc25, ymax = obsAcc97, x = x), fill = "cadetblue3", alpha = 0.8) +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = delAcc25, ymax = delAcc97, x = x), fill = "palegreen3", alpha = 0.8) +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = actAcc25, ymax = actAcc97, x = x), fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = 0.8) +
 theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey58"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey75"))

## No Toolstips at all
ggplotly(plot, tooltip = NULL)

## just the ymin from the aes is taken as label
ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("ymin"))

## Ymin/Ymax and X are taken as label.
ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("ymin", "ymax", "x"))
```

---

It also works with the dput of your data. Maybe *reinstall ggplot2 / plotly* and try again.

---

Plotting it in a **shinydashboard**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      plotlyOutput("plot")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot <- ggplot(mydata) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = obsAcc25, ymax = obsAcc97, x = x), fill = "cadetblue3", alpha = 0.8) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = delAcc25, ymax = delAcc97, x = x), fill = "palegreen3", alpha = 0.8) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = actAcc25, ymax = actAcc97, x = x), fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = 0.8) +
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey58"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey75"))
      ggplotly(plot, tooltip = NULL)
    })}
)
```

Comment: I tried adding hoverinfo = 'text', text = NULL into my ggplotly call and the gigantic tooltip still shows up.

Comment: See my last edit.. `ggplotly` has an argument called `tooltip`.

Comment: yes it still shows up with tooltip = NULL, unfortunately. However, I noticed that at the end of the huge tooltip, showing all my data, there is a weird double parentheses )) I don't know. Maybe a clue to where its getting this from.

Comment: You have a **comma** at the end of your ggplot call!

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem, I am including the plot as part of a tabPanel() and there is code after it, so the comma has to be there because it is part of the UI

Comment: Not in that example. If people run the code as you put it, they will get an error.

Comment: that is bizarre. I will try reinstalling plotly and ggplot2 and see what happens. As I mentioned above, maybe it has something to do with my plotly being displayed in a tabPanel in a shinydashboard? Maybe there are compatibility issues?

Comment: I dont think so, as it works for me also in a shiny fluidPage and shinydashboard-Page. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I've tried everything you suggested, the tooltip still appears. I am at a loss. I was able to figure out though that the data the tooltip is showing is my x-axis data. If that helps at all.

Comment: Interesting.. When running my shinydashboard-example with the dput data, the problem is still there? Could you include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question?

Comment: added sessionInfo() output to original question.

Comment: After inspecting the HTML of the app, I think I know the issue. It has the title of the tabPanel as a list containing all of my data. I don't know how to change the title of the tabPanel. Everytime I try title = "Plot", it gives me an error : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Answer (score 1):

Put the tooltip null:

```
ggplotly(a, tooltip = c(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

@SeGa's answer is a great for controlling the tooltip text, but if you want to completely hide the tooltip would be to set the underlying `hoverinfo` attribute to `"none"`

```r
style(ggplotly(plot), hoverinfo = "none")
```